# How do I enlarge zram?

Tags: zram

If I have zram installed on Ubuntu and I want to enlarge it. By default, I only have a 935 megabytes and I need more zram! Does anyone know how I could get more zram? I would like to have at least 3 gigabytes of zram.

Comment: Don't know if this is what you are looking for, but see the question "How to change zram size?" and my answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1105734/909021

Answer (score 0):

In reading this page: [Compressed RAM with zRAM](https://weirdfellow.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/compressed-ram-with-zram/), it appears that you set the size of the volume by editing the /etc/init/zramswap.conf file and changing the line that points to your zRAM block device to match the size you want.

e.g. in terminal (CTRL+ALT+T):

```
$ echo 3221225472 > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
```

I've never used it myself, so I cannot guarantee that I'm even close to correct!

Comment: I don't have ubuntu currently installed, but I plan on reinstalling it, so I will test this when I do install it.

Comment: A belated welcome to AU ! Thank you for yr answer. Make sure however that, when you provide an answer, it is tested and proven to such an extent, that OP may place a degree of trust in it/you. Your last line is a very strong disclaimer that runs against that principle.