# zRAM, increasing size - 16.04/Xenial

Tags: 16.04, swap, zram

How to control zram seems to be quite confusing.  I'd like to change my zram size from 8G to 10G, and maybe later to 12G (I have a total of 16G).  I have gone into /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf and changed COMPCACHE_SIZE to "10G", after which I did `update-initramfs` and rebooted, but that didn't make any change.  I do have `zram-config` installed, which gives me:

`NAME       ALGORITHM DISKSIZE DATA COMPR TOTAL STREAMS MOUNTPOINT
/dev/zram0 lzo           1.9G   4K   81B   12K       1 [SWAP]
/dev/zram1 lzo           1.9G   4K   81B   12K       1 [SWAP]
/dev/zram2 lzo           1.9G   4K   81B   12K       1 [SWAP]
/dev/zram3 lzo           1.9G   4K   81B   12K       1 [SWAP]`

Looking at the man page for `zramctl`, another approach appears to be to create a zram4 device:

`zramctl zram4 -s <size> -a lzo`

though in that case I am not sure whether to use 2G, since every other device seems to be 1.9G.  Once done, do I need to do mkswap and swapon?
  And if so, will that stick past a reboot?  Also, one person claims that [zramctl will only compress "up to half of your ram"](https://askubuntu.com/q/56673/242522), though [this script from the Debian wiki seems to indicate that 75% is possible](https://askubuntu.com/a/544250/242522).

Searching here on askubuntu, I find various other answers, including [using zramctl to change the size of an already given device](https://askubuntu.com/a/796593/242522).  Another answer [suggests to edit /usr/bin/init-zram-swapping](https://askubuntu.com/a/819252/242522), which is the new location for /sbin/zram-config-start (see /etc/init/zram-config.conf).  Yet another answer, found a couple of different places, suggests [directly editing /sys/block/zram*/disksize](https://askubuntu.com/a/695648/242522).  Going back further, there are even more answers including [adding an /etc/init.d/zram](https://askubuntu.com/a/544250/242522), [editing /etc/rc.local](https://askubuntu.com/a/57048/242522) and [editing /etc/init](https://weirdfellow.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/compressed-ram-with-zram/).  So before breaking an already working system, could someone clue me in?

1. Why doesn't editing /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf work?
2. Why are my zram* device sizes 1.9G rather than 2.0G?
3. Should I create a new 1.9G/2.0G device with zramctl? (Which size?)
4. Or should I use zramctl to resize an already existing device? (By how much?)
5. Or should I edit /usr/bin/init-zram-swapping?
6. Or should I resize a device by editing /sys/block/zram*/disksize?
7. Or should I use any of the /etc/init*, /etc/rc.local approaches?
8. And, can I compress more than half of my RAM with any of these methods?
9. Also, what do I need to do to make it stick past a reboot?

I'd be interested in not only which approach might work, but also why there is this confusing thicket of answers.